# Speeding up SQL query(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

New to SQL Server so I am sorry if this is not correctly. We have a number of stored procedures. The one shown below is a good example.

The issue with the query is it works fine until there are thousands of records and it sometimes never returns. I am told this could be performance related and that queries like this could be improved by using local variables. Any insight would be appreciated...thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Status_GetObjectConfigurationsPr]  
    @SiteID   int,  
    @AnalogBinary bit,  
    @UserID   int,  
    @ActionNumber  int  
AS  
    DECLARE @ProcName  varchar(128),  
            @ErrorText varchar(200),  
            @ErrorID   int,  
            @RoleID    int  
 
    SELECT @RoleID = RoleID      
    FROM TESUserRole 
    WHERE UserID = @UserID  
  
    SELECT @ProcName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)  
  
    SELECT  
        o.ObjectID,  
        o.ObjectName,  
        o.ObjectType,      
        o.ObjectURI, 
        o.KeyName,  
        c.UserDefinedUnits,    
        o.SiteID,  
        ts.SiteName,  
        p.Device_ID,  
        c.Dimension,
        CASE 
           (SELECT COUNT(ParentObjectID) FROM TESObjectParent 
            WHERE ChildObjectID IN (o.ObjectID)) 
           WHEN 2 
              THEN (SELECT TOP 1 b.ParentObjectID 
                    FROM TESObject a     
                    INNER JOIN TESObjectParent b ON a.ObjectID = b.ParentObjectID  
                    WHERE a.ObjectID IN (SELECT ParentObjectID 
                                         FROM TESObjectParent 
                                         WHERE ChildObjectID IN (o.ObjectID)) 
                      AND ObjectType != 8 
                      AND RelationshipType = 7)  
           WHEN 1 
              THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ParentObjectID 
                    FROM TESObjectParent 
                    WHERE ChildObjectID = o.ObjectID AND RelationshipType = 7) 
        END AS ParentObjectId,
        CASE 
      (Select  count(ParentObjectID) from TESObjectParent where ChildObjectID in (o.ObjectID) ) 
      When  2 Then ((select top 1 ObjectName from TESObject a inner join TESObjectParent b 
                    on a.ObjectID = b.ParentObjectID  where a.ObjectID in 
                        (Select   ParentObjectID from TESObjectParent where ChildObjectID in (o.ObjectID)) 
            and ObjectType != 8 and  RelationshipType = 7))  
       
    When 1 Then PanelName 
 End
  as  PanelName  
FROM  
 TESObject o  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
 TESObjectConfiguration c  
ON  
 o.ObjectID = c.ObjectID  
INNER JOIN  
 TESSite ts  
ON  
 o.SiteID =ts.SiteID  
INNER JOIN  
 TESPanel p  
ON  
 o.Device_ID = p.Device_ID and o.SiteID = p.SiteID  
INNER JOIN  
  TESObjectFamily f  
ON  
  o.CustomFamilyNumber = f.FamilyNumber  
INNER JOIN  
  TESEquipmentRole er  
ON  
  er.FamilyID = f.FamilyID AND er.ObjectType = o.ObjectType   
INNER JOIN  
  TESAction a  
ON  
  er.ActionID = a.ActionID  
WHERE  
 
 p.IsAppliedToLicense = 1 AND p.IsPanelEnabled = 1  
AND  
 o.SiteID = @SiteID  
AND  
 (c.Property_ID = 85 OR c.Property_ID is NULL)  
AND(  
  (@AnalogBinary = 0 AND o.ObjectType IN (4,5))  
 OR  
  (@AnalogBinary = 1 AND o.ObjectType IN (1,2))  
 )  
AND  
  er.RoleID = @RoleID  
 AND   
  a.ActionNumber = @ActionNumber  

 
  
SET @ErrorID = @@ERROR  
  
IF @ErrorID <> 0  
 BEGIN  
  SET @ErrorText = 'Unable to retrieve Object Configuration Information.'  
  GOTO ErrorHandler  
 END  
  
---- Error Handling  
RETURN 0  
  
ErrorHandler:  
BEGIN  
 RAISERROR ('PROC: %s - %s , Error: %d.', 16, 1, @ProcName, @ErrorText, @ErrorID)  
END  
RETURN 1
```

Comment: FYI, it's advised for new development work you use `THROW`, not `RAISERROR`, and you really shouldn't be using that old `IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO...` logic. Every supported version of SQL Server supports `TRY...CATCH`.

Comment: Hard to say [without seeing the execution plan](https://pastetheplan.com). Most likely, the optimizer is struggling with parameter sniffing, `OR` predicates and terrible indexing